# How does one get the system time in XML? Is there a method/function?

Tags: xml, parsing, xsd

I am using an XML file to store data and parameters which is to be used by a parser, however in that XML I also have to use system time.  So, is there any built-in functionality in XML to get system time, perhaps something similar to getTime() in Javascript?

Comment: Did you really think that XML was a programming language?

Comment: What do you mean John Saunders? Of course XML is a programming language :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use XSLT, its possible to call a custom-supplied function to get the time. Is this what you were thinking of ?

So basically, you will transform your xml into another xml before reading it. The transform will add all the time elements.

Answer (score 8):

No.  XML is not a programming language.  It doesn't contain methods that perform actions.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just have the parser insert the current system time?

Answer (score 1):

> Extensible Markup Language,
>   abbreviated XML, describes a class of
>   data objects called XML documents and
>   partially describes the behavior of
>   computer programs which process them.
>   XML is an application profile or
>   restricted form of SGML, the Standard
>   Generalized Markup Language [ISO
>   8879]. By construction, XML documents
>   are conforming SGML documents.
>
> XML documents are made up of storage
>   units called entities, which contain
>   either parsed or unparsed data. Parsed
>   data is made up of characters, some of
>   which form character data, and some of
>   which form markup. Markup encodes a
>   description of the document's storage
>   layout and logical structure. XML
>   provides a mechanism to impose
>   constraints on the storage layout and
>   logical structure.

From [Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-intro)

You can get the system from a server side language and build that entity to your XML document.

From javascript you can get the client time which might not be  reliable source for any critical data.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will help you:

```
<datetime>
   <date>System.getDate()</date>
   <time>System.getTime()</time>
  <makeXMLAProgrammingLanguage> yes please </makeXMLAProgrammingLanguage>
</datetime>
```